# Associating data with additional data generated according to gaussian or exponential distribution

Tags: python, numpy

I have data in the following form:

```
a b c d.
e f g h.
i j k l.
m n o p.
```

Now I want to associate each row with an additional attribute lying between 0 and 1.  For example, I want to associate the additional attribute (lying between 0 and 1) in the following manner:

```
a b c d 0.5.
e f g h 0.4.
i j k l 0.65.
m n o p 0.78.
```

I want to generate the attribute according to some distribution like Uniform, Gaussian, Exponential. For uniform I can generate distribution using numpy.random.uniform using something like s = np.random.uniform(-1, 0, 1000). But I am not sure how to generate Gaussian and Exponential distributions. I'll be really thankful if someone can explain by an example as to how can I generate data according to Gaussian and Exponential distribution and associate it with my data.

Comment: Gaussian is also known as the normal distribution. Have you looked at 'numpy.random.normal'?

Similarly, 'numpy.random.exponential' may also help.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate random numbers drawn from different distributions using the [`numpy.random`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) module:

```
# uniform
s = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)

# gaussian, mean=0.5, std=0.2
s = np.random.normal(0.5, 0.2, 1000)

# exponential 
s = np.random.exponential(0.12, 1000)

# you might want to clip values between 0 and 1
s = np.clip(s, 0, 1)
```